# How to get Garage if full if there are more cars inside then parkingspaces availible

Tags: java

I  have this Garage Class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Garage {
    private int m3;
    private String name;
    private int parkingSpace;


    List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();

    public Garage(int m3, String name, int parkingSpace) {
        this.m3 = m3;
        this.name = name;
        this.parkingSpace = parkingSpace;

    }

    public int getM3() {
        return m3;
    }

    public void setM3(int m3) {
        this.m3 = m3;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getParkingSpace() {
        return parkingSpace;
    }

    public void setParkingSpace(int parkingSpace) {
        this.parkingSpace = parkingSpace;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Garage{" +
                "m3=" + m3 +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", parkingSpace=" + parkingSpace +
                '}';
    }
    public void addCar1(Car newCar) {
        if (cars.size() != parkingSpace)
            cars.add(newCar);
    }
    public int getHowManyCarsFit() {
        return parkingSpace - cars.size();
    }
    public int getHowManyCarsAreIn() {
        return cars.size();
    }

    public void addCar(Car newCar) {
        cars.add(newCar);
    }

}
```

Here example of one of  my garages (one that have the most cars)

```
Garage garage4 = new Garage(450, "garage4", 4);
        garage4.addCar(car1);
        garage4.addCar(car2);
        garage4.addCar(car3);
        garage4.addCar(car4);
        garage4.addCar(car5);
```

So it should sout that "This garage is full !" when i add  "car5" and ofcourse if there are 4 cars already

I try to do the folowing :

I took already  how many cars i have in and witch is the garage with most cars.
Now i have to say  if my garage have tha amount of casr af parking spcae or more cars the  the parkingspaces "Garage is full! Please park outside!"

This is my  code and what i have tryed in  else  if statmet

```
 public static Garage getMostCars(List<Garage> garageList) {
        Garage mostCars = null;
        int cars = 0;
        for (Garage garage : garageList) {
            if (garage.getHowManyCarsAreIn() > cars) {
                mostCars = garage;
                cars = garage.getHowManyCarsAreIn();
            } else if (garage.getHowManyCarsAreIn() >= garage.getHowManyCarsFit()) {
                System.out.println("----------------------------");
                System.out.println("Garage is full !  \n" + "You cannot add more cars , please go outside the garage");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("There are currently: " + cars + " cars inside");
        return mostCars;
    }
```

Comment: For your first problem (`addCar(car5)` not stating "garage is full") have a look at your `addCar1(...)` method which actually does the check. I'd just change the condition to `cars.size() < parkingSpace`, i.e. if the number of cars has not yet reached the number of available slots.

Comment: I'm not sure about this if-else statement in your last snippet. Right now it only checks if the garage has some space left (i.e. checks the "else if") if the garage does not have more cars than the garages that have already been checked. I'd assume you either want that check for every garage (so just do another separate if-block instead of `else if`) or do it on the garage with the most cars (so do it after the loop).

Comment: @Thomas. I  am looking now ,  I hope  I can figure it oout
Thankyou very much !